# CURL Not returning anything

Tags: php, curl

I am currently trying to work with the Buffer API but I cannot even get CURL to return a error message.

I tried `print_r` on `$resp` but still just a blank page.

P.S I have checked with phpinfo that I do in fact currently have curl enabled which it is and it is version 7.30.0

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])){

  $code = "REMOVED";
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
      CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.bufferapp.com/1/oauth2/token.json',
      CURLOPT_POST => 1,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
          'client_id' => 'REMOVED',
          'client_secret' => 'REMOVED',
          'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/example',
          'code' => 'REMOVED',
          'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
      )

  ));
  $resp = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
}
```

Edit:

I added the following lines of code before closing the curl

```
echo curl_errno($curl);
echo curl_error($curl);
```

And this was returned

> 60SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: Do you get any errors when you add error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); to the top of the page? Also add the following IF statement...

if(curl_exec($churl) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}

Comment: The following is returned. 'Warning: curl_error(): 2 is not a valid cURL handle resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\tuffer\index.php on line 32
Curl error:' Line 32 is your suggestion 'if(curl_exec($curl) === false) { echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl); }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are directly passing an array to the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, its assume this as multipart form posting request. Use the function `http_build_query` over your array.

```
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query( array(
      'client_id' => 'REMOVED',
      'client_secret' => 'REMOVED',
      'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/example',
      'code' => 'REMOVED',
      'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
  ))
```

Comment: print_r($resp) still returns a blank page.

Comment: Use the verbose mode to see what is actually happening `CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,`

Comment: I have updated the question, but I will also try your suggestion.